# ReportViewer and font-family

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, reportviewer, font-family

I implemented a web-portal in .Net which integrate a ReportViewer control to load SSRS reports. In order to customize the reports I use my own font in the rdl report file. Font is dynamically loaded on client side with a font-family declaration in css like it:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Helvetica 35 Thin';
src:url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.eot?#iefix');
src:url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/HelvNeue35_W1G.svg') format('svg');
```

}

All work perfectily on localy from Visual Studio with IIS Express : Font it's correctly loaded on each web browser and correctly displayed in report. That works also on my development server. But sinceI deployed on integration server, the font is not displayed.
I specify that I use the same SSRS server on local from Visual and on integration platform.

I investigated, and noticed a difference between the SSRS code generated by the ReportViewer control from IIS express and IIS 8.

In fact from Visual studio execution I found :

```
    .A6b8151803b1943dc956fcd4b577a57f413{word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;padding-left:2pt;padding-top:2pt;
    padding-right:2pt;padding-bottom:2pt;border:1pt none Black;
    background-color:Transparent;font-style:normal;
    font-family:'Helvetica 35 Thin';
```

And from IIS 8 I found :

```
    .A87918d1b077d4156abf69d70d7bd400213{word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;padding-left:2pt;padding-top:2pt;
    padding-right:2pt;padding-bottom:2pt;border:1pt none Black;
    background-color:Transparent;font-style:normal;
    font-family:Helvetica 35 Thin;
```

The quotes have been removed from IIS 8. As the font name contains space character, that explain why the font is not found by the browser.

Now I need to explain why the quote is removed from this platform. Anybody have encountered this issue?

Thank for you help.

Answer (score 0):

We've also just experienced this issue.
We fixed it by using an expression for the font name and setting it to

="'Font With Space In Name'"

If you are using IE then using compatibility mode may also fix the issue for you.